# the svnpoller is not triggered (warning in the twistd.log)

Tags: buildbot

I am not sure what is going on, but i get this weird issue with buildbot.

The SVNPoller is configured as it should (checked various config example files), when i run the buildbot checkconfig it says that everything is fine....but it won't work at all.

If i trigger a build via the scheduler class it works fine, i can retrieve the source updates and build without problems (tried with a 1h timeframe).

The problem thou is that the poller is not working, so even if i build each hour, the changes column stays empty (i get the changes for the various versions thou, so if i click on the build detail i can see the sourcestamp carrying the right and most recent revision everytime that i modify the codebase); so I have no way to know if the build fails who did the last change.

Another peculiar thing is that in the twistd.log i see this line:

```
Warning: no ChangeSources specified in c['change_source']
```

And i am not sure why it wouldn't work since the checkconfig does not raise any error.

The result of this is of course that the only thing built is the hourly one, leaving me without the poller, and without knowing who is putting code in each build.

This is the code for the poller:

```
    c['change source']=SVNPoller 
(svnurl="svn+ssh://user@svnserver.domain.com/svn/project/trunk,
pollinterval=60*5,
histmax=10,
project=myproj,
svnbin = '/usr/bin/svn')
```

So far it looks good, so I am not really sure what is wrong here...why the SVNPoller is not triggering any build.

Anyone that has some suggestions about why is this happening ? Is there any other way to get changes from an SVN server? I am a total newbie at BuildBot and I am not really getting too much out of the manual; that looks much more like a scholastic book instead of being a manual that shows you how you do stuff :)

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Ok, silly me :) the problem is the missing underscore on change_source...once added it the problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, silly me :) the problem is the missing underscore on change_source...once added it the problem is solved

```
c['change_source'] = SVNPoller (svnurl=source_svn_url,
                                pollinterval=60,    
                                histmax=10,
                                project='The_project',
                                svnbin= '/usr/bin/svn'  
                                )
```

this will poll the svn codebase at source_svn_url (just put your svn:// path); and will check every minute to see if anyone has done changes; and will keep 10 changes in the record list (any change after the 10th will not show up so use it carefully if you do a lot of commits).

Hope that this helps who uses buildbot!